# Pandoc in Typora procceses markdown with file that leads to error when run from PowerShell

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc

I have a markdown file (call it testfile.md) that I have created in Typora. When I export it to PDF from Typora it calls on Pandoc behind the scenes and the file is successfully created. However, when I attempt the conversion from Powershell I get a very pedantic sounding error message notifying that the desired PDF has not been created. Example:

```
Error producing PDF.
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>
```

Why is it that Pandoc is so intolerant of errors when executed in isolation (from PowerShell) in comparison to when it is executed from Pandoc? Is there a way to get Pandoc to ignore errors like these or to auto-correct them? For reference one of the commands I have tried is `pandoc testfile.md -o testfile.pdf` although all the others have so far yielded similar results.

Comment: What Pandoc command are you running in Powershell? Could you perhaps add it to the question? And is there a way to see what Pandoc command, including all options and flags, is run by Typora?

Comment: I have added one of the commands I have tried in PowerShell. Unfortunately I know of no way to see that commands that Typora is using...

Comment: Perhaps [the logs of Typora](http://support.typora.io/Get-Logs/) contain the pandoc command it uses? Also, [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/demos.html) has many options, perhaps you are not specifying the right pdf-engine for example?